# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I was trying to setup one of the open source project,During this when I run **make postgres**  cmd on ubuntu terminal then I am getting following error

```
-> Configure PostgreSQL database
-> Create database user 'vulnerablecode'
sudo -u postgres createuser --no-createrole --no-superuser --login --inherit --createdb vulnerablecode || true       
createuser: error: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "vulnerablecode" already exists
sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user vulnerablecode with encrypted password 'vulnerablecode';" || true
ALTER ROLE
-> Drop 'vulnerablecode' database
sudo -u postgres dropdb vulnerablecode || true
-> Create 'vulnerablecode' database
sudo -u postgres createdb --encoding=utf-8 --owner=vulnerablecode vulnerablecode
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/pankaj/About Code NextB/vulnerablecode'
-> Apply database migrations
venv/bin/python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/pankaj/About Code NextB/vulnerablecode/manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    command_line()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/pankaj/About Code NextB/vulnerablecode/vulnerablecode/__init__.py", line 22, in command_line
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/pankaj/About Code NextB/vulnerablecode/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:92: migrate] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/pankaj/About Code NextB/vulnerablecode'
make: *** [Makefile:103: postgres] Error 2
```

In the above error,the main thing to emphasis is No module named 'django.utils' but after seeings I tried to install it using sudo-apt-get install django-utils then I am getting following error.I am using WSL on windows 10.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package django.utils
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'django.utils'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'django.utils'
```

Comment: what is the Django version you are using?

Comment: do you have the virtual environment activated?